# Resultados Other an Unspecified en los campos LopMostSpecificTargetId AoiMostSpecificTargetId

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Usando las variables LopMostSpecificTargetId AoiMostSpecificTargetId he probado en incluirlo en el script para obtener dichos campos y en el sheet me salen lo resultados Unspecified an Other.

Sabéis el porque me salen estos datos y no la ubicación o pais del usuario?

Os pongo el script

```
function main() {
var spreadsheeturl = 'Hoja del Sheet';
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheeturl);
var active = sheet.getActiveSheet();
var report = AdWordsApp.report("SELECT AoiMostSpecificTargetId,LopMostSpecificTargetId FROM CLICK_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DURING YESTERDAY");
report.exportToSheet(active);
}
```

Comment: Favor de seguir las indicaciones de [ask]

Comment: ...en particular la parte de ayudar a otros a reproducir el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno he estado investigando y me ha comentado los de google adwords que estan teniendo un problema con estas variables, por eso no sale nada.